# Finding Out a file type

Tags: objective-c, file, types

How can one find out the type of a file in objective c,i.e, finding out whether the file is a a pdf,xls,doc or an image or a directory?

Comment: You might want to look at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213784/how-to-find-file-types-in-objective-c).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is against SO policy, but I wrote a high-level [wrapper](https://github.com/aidansteele/MagicKit) around `libmagic`, `MagicKit.framework`. It has an iOS target that you can statically link against your iOS application, if that's what you want. The feature set is somewhat spartan, but it does return [Uniform Type Identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Type_Identifier) (as well as MIME types and human-readable descriptions) if you want to broadly categorise your files into multimedia, documents, etc.

Comment: i used uidocumentInteractionController....and was able to find out file type......UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate was the delegate that i had implemented

Answer (score 0):

If you can't trust the extension to be accurate, you'll need to look at the "magic numbers", the first few bytes of the file.

Directories are a different animal. You can test that with stat() or its Objective-C equivalent.